# Why Label in if else condition not calling in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am applying search using a textbox and button and results are shown in GridView in ASP.NET.  If result do not match with the search then I want that the Label1 "your search do not match" should be visible. 
Here is issue that if search result do not match, Label1 is not called.
the code is given below:

```
SqlConnection con4 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=***; Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=***;");
SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select newsid, title, thumbnail,imagepath,imagename from addnews where (title like'%" + TextBox1.Text.ToString() + "%')", con4);
SqlDataAdapter sda4 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd4);
DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();

sda4.Fill(dt4);
if (dt4 != null)
{
    GridView3.DataSource = dt4;
    GridView3.DataBind();
}
else
{
    Label1.Visible = true;
}
```

ASPX markup

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Search do not match" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server"> </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you also show aspx code for gridview and label?

Comment: sure, <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Search do not match" Visible="False"></asp:Label>  <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>

Comment: I've added that to the question. Such updates should go to question by default. Another point - in which page event are you doing this? Page Load? Do you check for postback?

Comment: Thanks for guiding me, I will make sure to post aspx with the questions as well, I am not checking it for postback, and I am doing it in button click event:  protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer the below code:

```
DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();

sda4.Fill(dt4);
if (dt4.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView3.DataSource = dt4;
    GridView3.DataBind();
}
else
{
    Label1.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, A Patel, it did the job

Answer (score 1):

You check for dt4 != null, which will always be true because you initialize it as new Datatable(), so it will never go the "else" part of your statement, but simple put an empty dt4 in the source.